# TL-WN722N Connection Problem

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I have a very weird problem here, can anyone help?
I just bought a TL-WN722N Wireless Adapter and my Linux Lite OS detected it.
The weird thing is I can't access the internet at all, however I can login to my router.
I can't really understand why, is it the driver? maybe because my TL-WN722N Version is 3.2 and the OS detected it as Version 2.

some details:

**uname -a**

`Linux hydra 5.4.0-89-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 24 14:50:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**iwconfig**

```
usb0      no wireless extensions.

wlx28ee520dc324  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"TP-LINK_4DB9E3"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 34:E8:94:4D:B9:E3   
          Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=60/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

ens5      no wireless extensions.
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 18d1:4ee3 Google Inc. Nexus 4/5/7/10 (tether)
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2357:010c TP-Link TL-WN722N v2
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

**sudo lshw -class network**

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:84:00.0
       logical name: ens5
       version: 02
       serial: 1c:c1:de:b4:e3:41
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90410000-90410fff memory:90400000-9040ffff memory:90700000-9071ffff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:6
       logical name: usb0
       serial: f6:4f:dc:ea:26:94
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.150 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:1
       logical name: wlx28ee520dc324
       serial: 28:ee:52:0d:c3:24
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=192.168.1.115 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID `2357:010c` is for TL-WN722N v2 and v3. See [The USB ID Repository](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids)

```
2357  TP-Link
    ...
    010c  TL-WN722N v2/v3 [Realtek RTL8188EUS]
    ...
```

The driver can be installed from this git repo:  [quickreflex/rtl8188eus](https://github.com/quickreflex/rtl8188eus)

**Edit**

A working driver test by [@mohamed.oussous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/500073/mohamed-oussous) using the more recent driver on [aircrack-ng](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus).

Installation steps:

```
sudo apt install dkms bc libelf-dev build-essential git
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone -b v5.3.9 https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus.git
cd rtl8188eus/
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Comment: ok thanks, but how to install RTL8188EUS driver

Comment: @mohamed.oussous I have added a link.

Comment: thank you very mush, it worked after I installed rtl8188eus driver, but the repo you mentioned did not compile, I end up using this repo: [aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus)